# How to use echarts in ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js

I'm finding the way to use Echarts library on my ExpressJS project.
It has npm package "echarts", however there is no document on how to use it.
I would like to create chart and get it Base64 image.

Thanks

Comment: You can still use the Wayback Machine to browse the API documentation : http://web.archive.org/web/20190521214509/http://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/tutorial.html#Get%20Started%20with%20ECharts%20in%205%20minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echarts` is primarily a client-side library, Do you really want to render your charts at server side? It is not possible out of the box, but you can use headless tools to generate the images.

Look at puppeteer, headless chrome etc.,

Comment: I have to send an email with a chart in the body content. So this way need to install chromium browser in the server, right?

Comment: understand, you can use headless browsers to generate the charts then.